# call super based __callee__ value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, super

Method `super` calls parent method based on `__method__`.
How to call parent method based on `__callee__`?

```
class SomeLogic
  DICTIONARY = {
    new_method_1: 'dictionary value 1',
    new_method_2: 'dictionary value 2'
  }

  def initialize(method_name)
    @method_name = method_name
  end

  def call
    DICTIONARY[@method_name]
  end

end

module M

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def base_method
    logic = SomeLogic.new(__callee__).call

    if logic
      logic
    elsif defined?(__callee__)
      super # here analogue of super needed
    else
      {}
    end
  end

  alias_method :new_method_1, :base_method
  alias_method :new_method_2, :base_method
  alias_method :new_method_3, :base_method
end


class A

  prepend M

  def new_method_3
    'foo'
  end

end
```

Expected results:

```
A.new.new_method_1 # dictionary value 1
A.new.new_method_2 # dictionary value 2
A.new.new_method_3 # foo
```

Current results:

```
A.new.new_method_1 # dictionary value 1
A.new.new_method_2 # dictionary value 2
A.new.new_method_3 # no superclass method `base_method' for A
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change

```
class A
  prepend M
```

to

```
class A
  include M
```

you will get the desired output

Comment: `include` would not work if `SomeLogic::DICTIONARY` had a key for `:new_method_3` because this logic appears to need precedence over a defined method call

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is extremely convoluted but it will work as requested

```
class SomeLogic
  DICTIONARY = {
    new_method_1: 'dictionary value 1',
    new_method_2: 'dictionary value 2'
  }

  def initialize(method_name)
    @method_name = method_name
  end

  def call
    DICTIONARY[@method_name]
  end

end
module M

  def self.prepended(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  def base_method(&block)
    SomeLogic.new(__callee__).call || 
    block&.call || # ruby < 2.3 block && block.call
    {}
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def method_added(method_name)
      if M.instance_methods.include?(method_name)
        orig = M.instance_method(method_name)
        M.remove_method(method_name)
        new = self.instance_method(method_name)
        self.prepend(Module.new do 
          define_method(method_name) do
            result = orig.bind(self).call(&new.bind(self))
          end   
        end)
        M.define_method(method_name, &orig.bind(M))  
      end
    end
  end

  alias_method :new_method_1, :base_method
  alias_method :new_method_2, :base_method
  alias_method :new_method_3, :base_method
  alias_method :new_method_4, :base_method
end

class A
  prepend M
  def new_method_3
    'foo'
  end
end

class B 
  prepend M 
end
```

So when you define a new method we check to see if that method is already defined by `M`. If so then we capture that `UnboundMethod` remove the method from `M`, then we capture the new definition as an `UnboundMethod`  then define the new method in an anonymous `Module` as `M`s implementation passing the new method implementation as a proc to `M`s implementation and prepend this module to the defining `Class`, then we place `M`s implementation back into `M` so other classes still work.

Result:

```
p A.new.new_method_1 
#=> 'dictionary value 1'
p A.new.new_method_2 
#=> 'dictionary value 2'
p A.new.new_method_3 
#=> 'foo'
p A.new.new_method_4
#=> {}
p B.new.new_method_3
#=> {}
```

If you would prefer `include` over `prepend` then `M` could look like

```
module M 
  def self.included(base)
    super
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  def base_method
    if logic = SomeLogic.new(__callee__).call
      logic
    elsif self.class.instance_methods(false).include?(__callee__)
      send(__callee__,true)
    else
      {}
    end
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def method_added(method_name)
      return if @_adding_method # avoid stack level issues
      if M.instance_methods.include?(method_name)
        new = instance_method(method_name)
        @_adding_method = true # avoid stack level issues
        define_method(method_name) do |bypass_parent=false|
          return super() unless bypass_parent
          new.bind(self).call
        end   
        @_adding_method = false
      end
    end
  end
end
```